# CentOS 7: after reboot, zfs module won't load, no /dev/zfs

Tags: centos, kernel-modules, zfs, modprobe

After 959 days a reboot was needed on the CentOS 7 system which has used ZFS flawlessly for the past years. I have run `yum update` once a month during that time.

The rebootet system is apparently unable to load its ZFS module, as evidenced by

```
# zpool list
/dev/zfs and /proc/self/mounts are required.
Try running 'udevadm trigger' and 'mount -t proc proc /proc' as root.
# modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found.
# uname -a
Linux foo 3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 30 15:51:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# yum install zfs zfs-kmod
Package zfs-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kmod-zfs-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

`/proc` is mounted and `udevadm trigger` has no effect. `/dev/zfs` does not exist. Grepping dmesg for ZFS (case insensitive) is empty. Manually loading the module says

```
# modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found.
```

I'm stumped. How can I get ZFS going again?

**Edit**

One problem was that my repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/zfs.repo` was still for 7.6, while `/etc/yum.repos.d/zfs.repo.rpmnew` was for 7.9. I have saved the old zfs.repo and copied the one for 7.9 onto `zfs.repo`. Then followed the instructions for kABI again. Now I'm getting this:

```
# yum install zfs
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package spl.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: spl = 0.7.13 for package: kmod-spl-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package zfs.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: zfs = 0.7.13 for package: kmod-zfs-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package zfs.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libzpool4 = 2.0.7 for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzfs4 = 2.0.7 for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libuutil3 = 2.0.7 for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnvpair3 = 2.0.7 for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzpool.so.4()(64bit) for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzfs_core.so.3()(64bit) for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzfs.so.4()(64bit) for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libuutil.so.3()(64bit) for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnvpair.so.3()(64bit) for package: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kmod-zfs.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be updated
---> Package kmod-zfs.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package libnvpair1.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
---> Package libnvpair3.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package libuutil1.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
---> Package libuutil3.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package libzfs2.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
---> Package libzfs4.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package libzpool2.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
---> Package libzpool4.x86_64 0:2.0.7-1.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package spl.x86_64 0:0.7.13-1.el7_6 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: spl = 0.7.13 for package: kmod-spl-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kmod-spl-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64 (@zfs-kmod)
           Requires: spl = 0.7.13
           Removing: spl-0.7.13-1.el7_6.x86_64 (@zfs-kmod)
               spl = 0.7.13-1.el7_6
           Obsoleted By: zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

# yum install --skip-broken zfs
[...]
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    kmod-zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
    libnvpair3-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
    libuutil3-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
    libzfs4-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
    libzpool4-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
    zfs-2.0.7-1.el7.x86_64 from zfs-kmod
```

How I can I resolve the dependency problems?

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit adding the solution to the question. If you have a solution that is not mentioned below, then consider adding your own answer and accepting that rather than modifying the question.  [This is totally acceptable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).  You may also modify (or suggest an edit to) a given answer, if it isn't complete enough.  Also, a question is considered "solved" when an answer is accepted, so tagging the title with "SOLVED" is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

959 days without reboot? Wow. I assume you are not using `kexec` so that means you have booted the new kernel for the first time. The problem is the ZFS module you have installed is build for a different kernel so you can't load it now.

Your options:

- Try using the `weak-modules` skript (`weak-modules --add-kernel --no-initramfs` if you don't need ZFS in initramfs). If there wasn't a kABI change it will symlink the module to the new `/lib/module` directory to make it usable with the new kernel. (If this is really the first time you are using a new kernel there probably was a kABI change.)
- If above doesn't work you can try reinstalling the packages. OpenZFS [mentions this](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/RHEL-based%20distro/index.html) as a necessary step when upgrading between CentOS minor versions.

  1. You'll need to remove the existing `zfs`, `spl` and `kmod-zfs` packages first with `yum remove zfs spl kmod-zfs`.
  2. Install the latest repository for 7.9 from [OpenZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/RHEL-based%20distro/index.html).

  ```
  yum install https://zfsonlinux.org/epel/zfs-release.el7_9.noarch.rpm
  rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-zfsonlinux
  ```

  3. Install `zfs` and `kmod-zfs` from the newly added repo.
- You can also try installing the [DKMS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/RHEL-based%20distro/index.html#dkms) module (which will be automatically rebuilt after a kernel update) instead of the kmod package you are using now.

Comment: Where would I find `weak-update`? It's not installed and `yum search weak` shows nothing appropriate. The OpenZFS page uses `rpm -E %distro` as part of a string which results in `%distro`, which looks odd. Would that part be `el7`? Thanks Vojtech!

Comment: Sorry, the script is called `weak-modules`.

Comment: The `rpm -E %distro` part really looks weird, the `%distro` is not a valid RPM macro on CentOS. The want `el7_X` where `X` is minor version so most likely `9` in your case (if you really have latest updates).

Comment: Hm. I followed the instructions for "kABI-tracking kmod", rebooted, still the same problem. I never used weak-update, how would I call it (which arguments)?

Comment: I upated the zfs.repo to use the current 7.9 instead of 7.6. I'm getting a bit further but now ran into a dependency problem. Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try removing the packages first (both `zfs` and `kmod-zfs`) and then installing them again. The documentation mention this. I'm not sure why they don't support upgrading the package, it shouldn't be hard, but they say "uninstall OpenZFS and then reinstall it".

Comment: That did it: `yum erase zfs kmod-zfs`, along with `yum erase spl`. After the reboot my pools are back! Btw, package `spl` seems gone with 7.9. You saved my life. :)